# Accessing annotations defined in the interface, in the class implementing it?

Tags: java, annotations

I'm working with java. I have an interface that has an annotated method in it. Is there a way to access that annotation in a class implementing that interface?

Thanks.

Edit: sorry, I shoudl've been clearer: I'm using reflection to access elements of Java, and I'm wondering how to access the annotations in a class implementing an interface (where the annotation is declared).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Reflection allows you to check for the presence of an annotation. There are methods at the class, method, paramter levels: [reflection and annotations](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/annotations.html)